# How to put button next to a input?

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble to put the button (enter) next to my input comment section.
I have tried many options like align=right and working on the paddings but it did not do the trick. When I take out the starts wrapper it works but doesn't when it is in it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! 
Thank you in advance

Here is a [Screenshot of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndLQd.png).

Here is my HTML:

```css
.BoxInfo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 1000px;
}

.BoxDesign {
  width: 70%;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 15px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  border-radius: 0.9rem;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.ButtonEnter {
  padding-top: 200;
  width: 60px;
  color: red;
}

.CommentSection {
  width: '100%';
  margin-right: -4px;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="BoxInfo">
  <div class="BoxDesign">
    <h3 class="police_fonce">My box</h3>
    <hr/>
    <h3>1 Info</h3>
    <h3 class="police_fonce">2 Info</h3>
    <h3 class="police_peu_fonce">3 Info</h3>

    <div class="ec-stars-wrapper">
      <a href="#" title="s1">&#9733;</a>
      <a href="#" title="s2">&#9733;</a>
      <a href="#" title="s3">&#9733;</a>
      <a href="#" title="s4">&#9733;</a>
      <a href="#" title="s4">&#9733;</a>
      <a id="textCom" href="#" title="s5">&nbsp;  Reviews</a>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="CommentSection" placeholder="Write a comment" />
    <Button class="ButtonEnter">Enter</Button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hm, it's worth noting when I popped it into JSFiddle it worked just fine! But here's an amended fiddle with some styling that may force yours to work! https://jsfiddle.net/edc1aj79/

Comment: I made a snippet of your code, but removed the unmatch div at the top (I assume a copy/paste error issue there)  It works here, please update with more information

Answer (score 0):

Just use `position:` and `left:` or `right:` in your CSS. Here is [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) and [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp) for reference.

You could do something like this:

```
position: absolute;
left: 500px;
```

Or

```
position: relative;
left: 50px;
```

Whichever you find best for you.

Comment: i dont think this is such a good idea. It is the start of developing bad habit.

Comment: @SuperSimplePimpleDimple How?

Comment: absolute positioning is not meant to be used in this way, and if it is overused it will lead to horrible design flaws especially when converting the website to mobile view. There is a reason why we have display properties. I wrote an answer above you can check it out see which one is better.

Answer (score 0):

So in order to make the button and the input have a relative position to one another, they need to share a common father (perferably an individual parent) so just put a wrapper div around them:

```
<div id="comment_container">
    <input type="text" class="comment_input comment_element" placeholder="Write a comment" />
    <Button class="comment_submit comment_element">Enter</Button>
</div>
```

Now that your elements share a common father - wrapper, you can start by adding a width value to the parent. Id keep this as a pixel value but you can convert it to % or vw or whatever. Then you will want to add a small margin to the button and the input (give them space to breath) and finally specifying their width. You can play around with the values or copy mine. Finally adjust height of both elements and enjoy the magic of good html and css.

```
.comment_element{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    border: none;
}
#comment_container {
    width: 400px;
    height: auto;
    background: #4278DD;
    padding: 10px 5px;
}
.comment_input {
    width: 300px;
}
.comment_submit {
    width: 80px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I added a few CSS tricks to spice things up.

Answer (score 0):

1. According to image you have to decrease the with of button like
   without quote.

   .CommentSection {
       width: 100%;
   }
2. As mention above your style need to change in padding-top of button (approx)

   .ButtonEnter{
       padding-top:20px;
       width:60px;
       color: red;
     }
3. or else try out bootstrap.